# Minimum value for a group of variables in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

I want to use linear programming to assign weights to a number of groups of variables.

Let's assume we have group $A$ with $x,y,$ and $z$ and group $B$ with $m,n,$ and $p$.

Is it possible to define constraints so that at least one of the variables from each group gets a weight larger than zero?

A feasible solution wout be $x=2,y=0,z=0$ and $m=3, n=0, p=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming the weights are integers.

Let $x_i^A$ denote the weight assigned to item $i$ from group $A$ and $x_i^B$ denote the weight assigned to item $i$ from group $B$.

You need the following constraints :
$$
\sum_{i} x_i^A \ge 1 \\
\sum_{i} x_i^B \ge 1 \\
x_i^A, x_i^B \in \mathbb{N}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid how simple the answer was!